# Arranging items in strictly increasing order

Tags: probability

"We throw 3 dice one by one. What is the probability that we obtain 3 points in strictly increasing order"?

Isn't the answer just $1/6$ as there are $3!$ possible permutations and only 1 permutation in which the 3 dice will be in strictly increasing order. However, the answer in my book is $5/54$.

Similarly, for the question of "what is the probability of 10 people being seated in strictly increasing order of age at a table?" Wouldn't the solution be $20/10!$ as direction of the increasing order has not been specified. I think this answer is correct whilst my answer for the previous question is wrong even though I am using the same logic and I can't see why this is, when they are effectively very similar questions.

Thank You

Comment: Hint:  what three events are you permuting for the dice case?  It is not true that there is only one way to get an increasing sequence. You could throw $\{1,2,3\}$,$\{1,2,4\}$,$\{4,5,6\}$ or many other cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For each selection of $3$ out of $6$ numbers, there is exactly one way to arrange them in order, so there are $\binom63=20$ different strictly ordered outcomes, which yields a probability of $20/6^3=5/54$.

For the seating question, your answer is correct if this is a round table and the we can start anywhere and move in either direction. The difference to the first case is that you're placing exactly those $10$ people, whereas in the case of the dice you can select some elements out of a larger set and then arrange them in order.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

For a *strictly increasing* sequence, you need three different numbers to show, and each such outcome has just *one* of strictly increasing sequence, hence

$Pr = \dfrac{\binom{6}{3}}{6^3}= \dfrac{20}{216}= \dfrac{5}{54}$

**PS**

I believe your answer for the 2nd question is correct for a round table. For seating in a row (assuming either direction) it would be $\dfrac{2}{10!}$

Comment: Then how does the factor $20$ arise?

Comment: My bad, amended.

Comment: I don't understand what "numbered" in boldface refers to. If the numbering has any significance, I would have expected it to mean that the increasing order of age would have to be consistent with the numbers, and that would yield $1$ possibility, not $20$. What other significance could a numbering have?

Comment: Well, it does seem a bit odd, but the youngest could be allotted any of 10 numbered seats, and the others arranged clockwise or anticlockwise with respect to the youngest to yield $\frac{20}{10!}$ which, of course is the same numerically as $\frac{2}{9!}$ for an unnumbered table. What I had meant was that the exact expression $\frac{20}{10!}$ as written by OP would arise for a numbered round table, but I get your point, and am editing it.

Comment: @trueblueanil So my answer for the second question is incorrect as I said $20/10!$? Could you explain how you get $2/10!$ please?

Comment: @Jojo: If they are seated in a row, there are only two arrangements in strictly ascending order, (left to right and right to left) against 10! possible arrangements

Comment: Thats a bit weird to me. Does it mean that if you arrange a set of integers in decreasing order it sould be called 'increasing from the right'?

Comment: @Alex: What you say is true for a set of integers by convention, but is there such a convention for people, too ? Seems like an Alice In Wonderland situation. If two directions are allowed on a round table, then why not in a row ? I concede that yours might be a more common view. Turning out to be an interesting question !

Answer (score 1):

The possible arrangements that make that happen, since the order counts, are
$123, 124, 125, 126, 134, 135, 136, 145, 146, 156, 234, 235, 236, 245, 246, 256, 345, 346, 356, 456$ , so there's $20$ of them.
How many arrangements are possible? Well, $6^3$ is the right answer so it's $216$.
$$\frac{20}{216} = \frac{5}{54}$$

Answer (score 0):

For 2) it is $\frac{1}{10!}$ assuming all people are of different age

Comment: But direction hasn't been specified. Isn't this a factor?

Comment: Direction-strictly increasing?